# mysql query orderby groupby,

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following key fields: `commentid`, `comment`, `time`, `parentid`

The comments are of two types, `regular` and `replies`.  Regular have parentid 0; replies have parentid equal to the commentid they reply to.

I thought I had this figured out with group by and orderby but my idea didn't work and I'm now struggling as my knowledge of sql is rudimentary.

I want it to display by time DESC except that I would like those with the same parentid grouped together and within that parentid, that they also be be sorted by time.  I am allowing only one level of reply.

As an example, I would like following order:

```
time3 commentid3 parentid0
time2 commentid2 parentid0
    parentid2 commentid4 time4 (this one is a reply)
    parentid2 commentid5 time5 (this one also reply)
time1 comment1 parentid0
```

I tried `SELECT * from comments GROUP BY parentid ORDER BY TIME DESC` but this did not work. If needed, I can add another column.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!  Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making a few assumptions here. I'm assuming your commentid is an auto-incrementing id, so that would mean that the insert order would be from oldest to newest. This will not work if you are not using auto-incrementing ids or if you have some kind of partial-save functionality with these tables. So it's kind of fragile.

I'm also assuming parent_id is null if it is the parent.

```
SELECT commentid, comment, time, parent_id, if(parent_id = 0, commentid, parent_id) thread 
FROM comments  
ORDER BY thread desc, time asc
```

Anyway to add some more information.

`Group By` is not what you want to use because it will group all rows by the grouping column into one row. `Group By` is usually used for aggregate calculations such as counting or summing the values in rows, etc.

EDIT:

I updated the query to sort by time asc, which will put the regular comment first and then the replies below the parent comment from oldest to newest.

Comment: How is thread set?  Is it the same as commentid?  if I understand this correctly, it outputs original threads.  I am trying to emulate disqus, livefyre with comments in time descending but with replies displayed indented below the comment they respond to.  The indenting is just a formatting issue, so I just need to have replies slotted beneath their respective parent comments.

Comment: Thread may not be the best word for it, but it's set by conditional if in the select clause. So if parent_id is null we will use commentid for the thread id. This is just for ordering and grouping all the comments together.

Comment: To clarify, Thread is not a real column, it is just an alias for the if function. We cheat here with thread because we assume the threads are entered in order from oldest to newest, and then each of the grouped comments are sorted by time column.

Comment: This comes close to working.  parentid is 0 if not a reply and commentids are time sequential except for reply so that part seems okay.  Output of query groups replies with what they reply to but puts replies on top of the original post rather than below...  The hard part seems to be the replies should sorted by time but only after they are sequenced below original comment

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean. Maybe change time desc to asc. That will make it so the regular comment is on top and then the replies are listed below from oldest to newest.

Comment: That worked.  Thx! Related question..When sites display comments by popular, do you think they place a field for reads in the comments table to order by?

Comment: I'm not sure. Depends on how you want to determine popular. Hard thing about reads is that all the comments will be displayed depending on how you're doing it. You have to determine popular using something like a count of "Likes" or "Thumbs up". So in that case you'd add a field for likes, etc, just like with your "reads" example. And yeah, it would probably be ordered by reads.

Answer (score 1):

You can't retrieve a "tree-like" result from a sql query (well there are ways, but they don't seem practically usable here)

What you can do is to retrieve all datas from regular and replies (which implies that "regular" datas will be replicated if they have many replies, and you'll have to treat them after getting the data, to get a "tree" result)

result will look like that

```
regular.time, regular.commentid, replies.commentid, replies.time
```

if regular has no comments, replies.commentid and replies.time will be null

Query (with a "self left join") would look like that (I moved some fields that seems to be useless now)

```
select 
regular.time as regulartime,
regular.commentid as regularid, 
replies.commentid as repliesid, 
replies.time as repliestime
from comments regular
left join comments replies on replies.parentid = parent.commentid
where regular.parentid = 0
order by regular.time desc, replies.time asc
```

Following your example, you should get

```
time3 commentid3 null       null
time2 commentid2 commentid4 time4 (this one is a reply)
time2 commentid2 commentid5 time5 (this one also reply)
time1 commentid1 null       nulll
```

Comment: Are you suggesting two tables, regular and replies?

Comment: I have to read up on aliases as I don't immediately understand syntax.

Answer (score 1):

To get both layers of the data, you will need a UNION of just the top-most layer of the original comment, and another for any POSSIBLE replies.  The first column of the first part of the query will hold a 1 or 2 for sorting purposes.  This will be used to float the original post to the top of the group for a given question... then, all replies will show in natural order after that.

Also, to retain the proper grouping by original date/time, I am preserving the original post comment time with the '2' CommentType records so they do stay grouped with exact same original time start basis, but grab the actual comment and time of the RESPONSE (alias "r") for their respective sorting.

```
select
      PreQuery.*
   from
      ( select
              '1' as CommentType,
              c.Time as OriginalTime,
              c.CommentID StartingCommentID,
              c.Comment,
              c.Time as LastTime,
              c.CommentID as EndCommentID
           from
              comments c
           where
              c.ParentID = 0
        UNION ALL
        select 
              '2' as CommentType,
              c.Time as OriginalTime,
              c.CommentID StartingCommentID,
              r.Comment,
              r.Time as LastTime,
              r.CommentID as EndCommentID
           from
              comments c
                 join comments r
                    on c.CommentID = r.ParentID
           where
              c.ParentID = 0 ) PreQuery
   order by
      PreQuery.OriginalTime DESC,
      PreQuery.StartingCommentID,
      PreQuery.CommentType,
      PreQuery.LastTime
```

This should give you the results I think you are looking for (slightly modified)

```
CommentType  OriginalTime  StartingCommentID  Comment  LastTime  EndCommentID
1            Time3         ID3                Comm3    Time3     ID3  <-- ID 3 IS the start
1            Time2         ID2                Comm2    Time2     ID2  <-- ID 2 is the start of next
2            Time2         ID2                Comm4    Time4     ID4     <- ID4 is reply to orig ID2
2            Time2         ID2                Comm5    Time5     ID5     <- another reply to ID2
1            Time1         ID1                Comm1    Time1     ID1  <-- start of new comment ID1
```

So, for all rows, the 2nd and 3rd columns will always represent the parent ID that is starting the first comment... and for those with comment type = 1, the comment, last time and end comment ID is the actual content from the starting comment.  For comment type = 2, the final comment, last time and end comment will be the ID of the RESPONSE record.